# Выводить в input number число и округлить его до сотых

Tags: javascript, html, input

Есть 2 поля input number, с помощью javascript значение введенное в одно перещитывает и выводит значение в другое поле

```
<input id="goods" type="number" oninput="makePrice();">
<input id="price" type="number" oninput="makeGoods();">

function makePrice()
{
var temp = document.getElementById("goods").value;
var price = temp * 0.14;//Здесь может быть другой коэффициент
document.getElementById("price").value = price;
}
```

Функция MakeGoods() аналогична(если пользователь захочет купить товар, на какую то цену, а не по кол-ву товара)
Как в поле input id=price сделать значение с плавающией точкой, чтобы показывало после запятой цену в копейках, даже если получается целое число, все равно чтобы выводило число,например 100.00.
В поле input id=goods наоборот, при введении цены,чтобы округляло до целого количества единиц товара.
Как это сделать, с помощью JS, или HTML, наведите на правильную мысль.

Comment: Math.round в помощь. там ничего сложного

Comment: Понял, ищу, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[`toFixed`](http://javascript.ru/number/tofixed) Вам в помощь.
Точно не понял что нужно, но... вот так:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('#goods').addEventListener('input', makePrice);
  document.querySelector('#price').addEventListener('input', makeGoods);
});

function makePrice(){
  let temp   = document.querySelector("#goods").value,
      factor = 0.14;
  
  document.querySelector("#price").value = (temp * factor).toFixed();
}

function makeGoods(){
  let temp   = document.querySelector("#price").value,
      factor = 0.36;
  
  document.querySelector("#goods").value = (temp * factor).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="goods" type="number" />
<input id="price" type="number" />
```